# Who's the alien in the Mel and Kim Christmas song?

Tags: character-identification

In 1987 Mel Smith and Kim Wilde released a cover version of "Rockin around the Christmas tree"

In the video of this song there is a scene (about the 1 minute 15 seconds mark) where Mel Smith goes dashing to the front door, an alien is shown for a few seconds, it is sitting on the stairs reading a newspaper.

I know the alien from something but can't remember what.

Screen cap from linked video:

[image: Alien reading newspaper]

[image: alien in comfortable chair]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this contemporary news article](https://www.wilde-life.com/sites/default/files/2018-02/19871121_nme.jpg) the cameo appearances include [The Mekon](https://britishcomics.fandom.com/wiki/Mekon) from the Dan Dare comics.

> Mel and Kim Mk II look set to provide us with the Christmas Number One, raising money for Comic Relief along the way. The new duo is Mel Smith and Kim Wilde, who have recorded a version of the Brenda Lee hit 'Rockin' Around The Christmas Tree', released by 10 Records on Monday.
>
> It's accompanied by an all-star video where the eagle-eyed among you should be able to spot Curiosity Killed The Cat, Spitting Image puppets, Father Christmas, **a Mekon**, 15 pumpkin pies (yet to be given their own record deal) and Griff Rhys-Jones.
>
> <sub><sup>New Musical Express (UK), November 21, 1987</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: It is indeed the Mekon, I used to read Dan Dare as a kid, and even played the computer game! (Which as I recall was unbeatable due to a bug)

Comment: Your answer has it right although the article is wrong: it's not "a" Mekon. The Mekon is a singular entity, leader of the Treens.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I'm on the hunt for a better source, tbh